# Problem in enabling fingerprint login in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa on Lenovo Ideapad 530S machine

Tags: lenovo, 20.04, fingerprint-reader

I am trying to enable the Fingerprint Unlock option in my Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fosaa (Lenovo Ideapad 530S) under `Settings > Users`

While trying to enable the `Fingerprint Login` option, the following error dialogue box shows up:
`Could not access any fingerprint readers. Please contact your system administrator for help.`

Moreover, I have tried running `lsusb` to check whether my system detects the fingerprint reader, and it does. The output is:
`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 27c6:5584 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader`

Can anyone check if they are facing the same problem and provide solution(s), if any. Thanks.

Comment: There are currently no Linux drivers available for this fingerprint scanner (Synaptics WBDI). https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:06cb-0081